# Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4n(2n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, infinity

How to evaluate this sum, derived from "Lockdown math" by 3Blue1Brown?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4n(2n+1)}$$

Comment: Hint: Can you write that fraction in terms of fractions with simpler denominators?

Comment: @PedroKK: Which video from 3Blue1Brown included this sum? How did you derive the sum - was it included at the end of a specific lockdown video?

Comment: I deduced it from a question proposed in the lockdown series. The question was about the probability that the floor of the division of two random numbers between 0 and 1 result in an even number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{4n(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{4n}-\frac{1/2}{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$$

Hence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ 4n(2n+1)} =\frac 12 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)= \frac 12\left(1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\right)=\ldots $$

where $${\displaystyle \ln(1+x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{n}}x^{n},\quad \ln(2)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{n}}}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{4n(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{4n}-\frac{1}{2(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{4n}-\frac{1}{4n+2}$$
Can you see where this is going?